# How can I programmatically trigger client side validation set up by a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little Ajax application where I use Razor views to initially generated HTML form segments that I later read and write from with knockout.js. Although I am doing no non-Ajax action requests, I use Razor to generate the HTML so I enjoy automatic generation of jQuery Validation attributes. E.g. in my single page, I render a hidden form like this:

```
<section id="person-detail">
    @Html.Action("EditPartial", "Person")
</section>
```

The `EditPartial` action returns a partial view that looks a lot like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { data_bind = "value: id" })
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { data_bind = "value: firstName" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <p>            
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: save">Update</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: delete">Delete</a>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Because I'm never actually posting the form, and due to some unknowns, despite all properties on my `Person` model being marked with the `Required` attribute, I see no sign of client side validation. What must I do to trigger this validation when my save button is clicked?

Comment: did you try `$("form").validate()`? or `$("form").valid()`?

Comment: Yes, but `Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'`. Same for `valid()`.

Comment: Did you makes sure that the jQuery and the unobtrusive jQuery validation scripts are both being referenced on the page?

Comment: can you show us the HTML actual sent to the browser. You are showing `EditPartial` in the Razor view. The actual HTML will have `data-*` attributes you can look for. Are these rendered?

Comment: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' is the error message when jquery validate is not referenced on the page. This doesn't sound to me to anything to do with Razor or knockout.js

Answer (score 20):

suppose your form has a class 'main':

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
            var $form = $('form.main');
            $form.valid();
    });
```

Comment: Note, .valid() will return true/false indicating if form is valid.  Also, I'm not sure if it will call preventDefault() for you to stop form submission or if you need to check the return value and call preventDefault() yourself.